# Does it follow that $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $1+2z+(2z)^2+(2z)^3+(2z)^4=0$ then it follows that $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Do we have to use a formula for a sum? Or how do we have to do that?

Comment: $1-c^{5}=(1-c)(1+c+c^{2}+c^{3}+c^{4})$.

Comment: That means in this case that $1-(2z)^5=0 \Rightarrow (2z)^5=1$, right? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Yes, now take absolue value on both sides.

Comment: Then we get $|2z|^5=1 \Rightarrow |z|=\frac{1}{2^5}\neq \frac{1}{2}$, right? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: No. $|2z|=(1)^{1/5}=1$

Comment: Ahhh I see!! And so it follows that $2|z|=1\Rightarrow |z|=\frac{1}{2}$ @KaviRamaMurthy